# Whats a simple way to get a text input Alertdialog box on an Android

Tags: javascript, titanium, titanium-mobile

I want to get the password. A simple text input dialog box. Any simple way to do this?

In iPhone it creates like this.

```
style : Ti.UI.iphone.AlertDialogStyle.SECURE_TEXT_INPUT
```

But in android how can I do thi??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently Appcelerator does not provide such facility. But you can do it in a simple way by using a view, textField and button as follows

```
var vwAlert = Ti.UI.createView({
    backgroundColor : '#311919',
    width       : '90%',
    height      : '40%',
    layout      : 'vertical',
    borderRadius: 5
}); 

var lblMessage = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    text        : 'Alert',
    top         : 10,
    color       : 'white',
    font        : {fontWeight : 'bold', fontSize : '16'}
});

var textField = Ti.UI.createTextField({
    width       :  '90%',
    top         :  '20',
        passwordMask: true,
    hintText    : 'Enter your text here',
    borderStyle     : Ti.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_ROUNDED,
    returnKeyType   : Ti.UI.RETURNKEY_RETURN,
    maxLength       : 70
});

var btnOK = Ti.UI.createButton({
    title   : 'OK',
    width   : '43%',
    top     : '25',
    font    : {fontWeight : 'bold', fontSize : '16'}
});

vwAlert.add(lblMessage);
vwAlert.add(textField);
vwAlert.add(btnOK);
```

The above view will look like an alert dialog box since it's customized one. This will do the trick :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the androidView property in a UI.AlertDialog and add a TextField.

Answer (score 0):

you need an EditText with `android:inputType="textPassword"`

Answer (score 0):

```
EditText tf = new EditText(context);

tf.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
```

or in xml

```
android:inputType="textPassword"
```

Comment: he is doing with titanium I think.